# Не понимаю принцип переворота строки

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки, substring

```
public class StringReverseAlgorithm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverseStringWithRecursion("Как это работает?"));
    }
    public static String reverseStringWithRecursion(String inputString) {
        String rightPart;
        String leftPart;

        int length = inputString.length();

        // заканчиваем рекурсивный обход
        if (length <= 1) {
            return inputString;
        }
```

Что происходит в следующих 2 строках? Почему мы доходим до среднего символа в leftPart, начинаем с того же среднего символа в rightPart, но символ не дублируется?

```
        leftPart = inputString.substring(0, length / 2);

        rightPart = inputString.substring(length / 2, length);
```

Почему, если мы меняем местами только правую и левую часть, переворачивается вся строка, то есть все символы записываются в обратном порядке?

```
 return reverseStringWithRecursion(rightPart) + reverseStringWithRecursion(leftPart);
    }
}
```

Comment: _но символ не дублируется_, зачем дублировать символ?
_все символы записываются в обратном порядке_ потому что рекурсивно функция вызывается до 1 символа

Comment: Я понимаю, что дублировать средний символ не нужно, но в этом коде он как будто дублируется (так как одна часть строки заканчивается символом length / 2, а другая с этого символа начинается)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы пишете `str.substring(a, b)`, то вы берёте подстроку с символа с номером a, до символа с номером b - 1, в терминах математики вы указываете **полуинтервал** [a, b), то есть левый конец включается, а правый нет.

В строках

```
leftPart = inputString.substring(0, length / 2);
rightPart = inputString.substring(length / 2, length);
```

вы берёт строку `[1 .. n]` (это написаны индексы символов) и разваливаете её в две подстроки:

`[1 .. n/2 - 1]` и `[n/2 .. n]`,

затем каждую из них переворачиваете рекурсивным вызовом, получаются строки

`[n/2 - 1 .. 1]` и `[n .. n/2]`,

и, меняя местами, склеиваете обратно, получается:

`[n .. n/2] + [n/2 - 1 .. 1] = [n .. n/2 n/2 - 1 .. 1] = [n .. 1]`,

строка в обратном порядке, что и было заявлено.

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ zcorvid:
В конце мы передаём строку в принимаемое значение, что приводит к тому, что метод выполняется заново и это происходит до тех пор, пока половины строк больше одного символа

Answer (score 0):

> Почему мы доходим до среднего символа в leftPart, начинаем с того же среднего символа в rightPart, но символ не дублируется?

Читайте документацию. В классе `String` метод `substring` принимает на вход *полуоткрытый* интервал `[а, b)`. То есть правый край интервала *не входит* в возвращаемую подстроку. Таким образом, никакого "дублирования символа" тут нет и не должно быть. Символ с индексом `length / 2` попадет только в правую подстроку, но не в левую.

> Почему, если мы меняем местами только правую и левую часть, переворачивается вся строка, то есть все символы записываются в обратном порядке?

Мы не просто меняем местами правую и левую часть. Мы еще предварительно выполняем рекурсивный вызов той же самой функции `reverseStringWithRecursion` для правой и левой части в отдельности. В результате правая и левая части переворачиваются. Несложно убедиться, что это приведет к перевороту исходной строки.